# In postgresql, how to drop a table available from a particular schema

Tags: postgresql

I've created a table with the name `customer` in schema x and I've created a view with the same name `customer` in schema Y.

How to drop the view from schema Y without checking dependencies for the table available in schema x?

Comment: `drop view y.view_name;`?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: it is trying to drop from both schems